# USB debugging switches off automatically

Tags: usb-debugging

I'm using a Huawei P20 Pro.

I'm trying to use `adb` according to this guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.

I have enabled developer options. I can enable USB debugging, but if I go back one screen and return, USB debugging is off again.

And ideas on how I can enable USB debugging?

Comment: This sounds like a device/manufacturer specific issue. Did you try looking for related settings in the developer settings screen? Maybe revoke all USB-debugging authorizations and then reconnect?

Comment: Please have a look to the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496745/usb-debugging-option-on-my-android-keeps-turning-off/54040795#54040795

Comment: The following solution might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496745/usb-debugging-option-on-my-android-keeps-turning-off/54040795#54040795

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is choosing "File Transfer" on android when you plug the USB instead of "Charge only"